# Displaying a strongly typed partial in a strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

Can I not render a strongly typed partial in a strongly typed view?

I am getting the following error when I try to:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.Table`1[UI.Models.vwProject]', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[UI.Models.ProjectStatus]'.

I populate both the views using ViewData.Model

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData.Model = project.vw_Projects;
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ProjectStatus()
{
    ViewData.Model = project.ProjectStatus;
    return View();
}
```

Here is my View:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<UI.Models.vwProject>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <div>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Project
        </th>
        <th>
            Hours
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ProjectCode) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ProjectHours) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<div>
 <%  Html.RenderPartial("ProjectStatus"); %>
</div>

</asp:Content>
```

Here is my partial:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<UI.Models.ProjectStatus>>" %>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Code
            </th>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.ProjectCode) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.ProjectStatus) %>
            </td>
        </tr>

    <% } %>

    </table>
```

I am a little confused with how to display strongly typed/dynamic partials in strongly type or dynamic views. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't you need to pass in a specific object into `RenderPartial`?  If you don't, it's getting the Model from the calling View.

Comment: @TLS yes, I do need to pass a specific object into RenderPartial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render a partial it won't hit you controller action just renders out the view with using the partent's view model by default.

If you want call your controller action `ProjectStatus` then what you need is the [RenderAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728607%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method:

```
<%  Html.RenderAction("ProjectStatus"); %>
```

A good article about [When to use RenderAction vs RenderPartial with ASP.NET MVC](http://captaincodeman.com/2009/02/21/when-to-use-renderaction-vs-renderpartial-with-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: When is it appropriate to use dynamic views and partials?

Comment: @user793468 it is hard to answer your question in general without a given context maybe you should ask a different question... I personally never use dynamic views only strongly typed ones... and we use partials when the view can be rendered with the model at hand and no additional code needs to be run in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. But if you don't pass a model to RenderPartial it will use the model from view.
So, you need to do something like that:

```
Html.RenderPartial("ProjectStatus", new List<ProjectStatus>()); %>
```